# Vim: Execute Goyo plugin when opening Markdown file

Tags: vim

So far I've got this:

```
autocmd Filetype markdown call SetUpMk()
function SetUpMk()
    colorscheme pencil
    execute 'Goyo'
endfunction
```

But that doesn't work. No errors or nothing, it just does nothing. The function is allright, because the colorscheme is being set to pencil. Should be that hard, right? I basically just want vim to do :Goyo when I open a file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call a function, just add:

```
au FileType markdown colorscheme pencil | Goyo
```